# Number of ways in which you can make a cuboid of particular dimension

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this problem in an interview. I could not figure out a way apart from taking all possibilities—i.e., complete brute force.

> You have 3 kind of cubes 1×1×1, 1×2×1, and 1×1×2. How many ways can you make a cube of dimension 1×2<sup>n</sup>×k using the above types of cubes?

Comment: What are the constraints of n and k? Can you rotate the cubes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for reduce this question i delete one constant dimension .

> this question is simple:
>
> we have 2 kind of  1*1,1*2 Squares,
>
> > HOW MANY WAYS you can make a Square
> >     of dimension 2^n X k using the above type of Squares?

and this question equal by:
how many [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in [Lattice graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_graph) with 2^n X k size?

because for each match we have one pattern to fill our Square,that set (1*2 Square) where the edge is match.and for other square set (1*1 Square)

i guess [Matching polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_polynomial) & [Bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) is useful.

in same question with(n=1) you can use recursive function to solve it.and it is easy to prove that the result is between [fibonacci_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and [Catalan_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)(for more details see Fibonacci numbers and Brick Wall Patterns in [this link](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibpuzzles.html))